# Are these jQuery if statements getting the element by ID correctly?

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement, getelementbyid

Please help. I'm trying to get html to show up depending on the ID of the li. I thought I knew what I was doing, but it always helps for someone else to look at it.

```
<div id="calcchooser">
<ul>
<h3>Black and White</h3>
    <li id="bwsoftcover" class="calcbutton s">Paperback</li>
    <li id="bwhardcover" class="calcbutton">Hardcover</li><br><br>
<h3>Standard Color</h3>
    <li id="standardpaperback" class="calcbutton">Paperback</li>
    <li id="standardhardcover" class="calcbutton">Hardcover</li><br><br>
<h3>Premium Color</h3>
    <li id="premiumpaperback" class="calcbutton">Paperback</li>
    <li id="premiumhardcover" class="calcbutton">Hardcover</li><br><br>
<h3>Ebook</h3>
<li id="ebook" class="calcbutton">Ebook</li><br><br>
<h3>Selected Product: <span id="selectedproduct">Black and White Paperback</span></h3>
```

```
$("#calcchooser li").click(function () {

var bwsoftcover = "Black and White Softcover"
var bwhardcover = "Black and White Hardcover"
var standardsoftcover = "Standard Color Softcover"
var standardhardcover = "Standard Color Hardcover"
var premiumsoftcover = "Premium Color Softcover"
var premiumhardcover = "Premium Color Hardcover"
var ebook = "Ebook"

$("#percentchooser li").removeClass("s");
$(this).addClass("s");

if( $(this).is('#bwsoftcover'); )    
    {$("#selectedproduct").hide().html(bwsoftcover).fadeIn();}
if( $(this).is('#bwhardcover'); )    
    {$("#selectedproduct").hide().html(bwhardcover).fadeIn();}
if( $(this).is('#standardsoftcover'); )    
    {$("#selectedproduct").hide().html(standardsoftcover).fadeIn();}
if( $(this).is('#standardhardcover'); )    
    {$("#selectedproduct").hide().html(standardhardcover).fadeIn();}
if( $(this).is('#premiumsoftcover'); )    
    {$("#selectedproduct").hide().html(premiumsoftcover).fadeIn();}
if( $(this).is('#bwhardcover'); )    
    {$("#premiumhardcover").hide().html(premiumhardcover).fadeIn();}
if( $(this).is('#ebook'); )    
    {$("#selectedproduct").hide().html(ebook).fadeIn();}


});
```

CSS if desired

```
li {
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
margin-right:5px;
position:relative;
cursor:pointer;
}

#calcchooser h3 {
font-weight:bold;
font-size:24px;
}

.calcbutton {
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #63b8ee), color-stop(1, #468ccf) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #63b8ee 5%, #468ccf 100% );
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#63b8ee', endColorstr='#468ccf');
background-color:#63b8ee;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:6px;
border:1px solid #3866a3;
display:inline-block;
color:#14396a;
font-family:arial;
font-size:13px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:3px 7px;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #7cacde;
}.calcbutton:hover {
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #468ccf), color-stop(1, #63b8ee) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #468ccf 5%, #63b8ee 100% );
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#468ccf', endColorstr='#63b8ee');
background-color:#468ccf;
}.calcbutton:active {
position:relative;
top:1px;
 }
```

/* This imageless css button was generated by CSSButtonGenerator.com */

Comment: Your `ul` is invalid HTML (the ***only*** valid child elements of a `ul`, or `ol`, is an `li` element, which itself can enclose other elements).

Comment: You should not have `;` inside your `if` condition as it will end the statement

Comment: Thanks. fixed that, but the jQuery still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var opts = {
    bwsoftcover: 'black and white paperback',
    bwhardcover: 'black and white hardcover',
    standardpaperback: 'standard color softcover',
    standardhardcover: 'standard color hardcover',
    premiumpaperback: 'premium color softcover',
    premiumhardcover: 'premium color hardtcover',
    ebook: 'ebook'
};

$('#calcchooser li[id]').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('s').siblings().removeClass('s');
    var text = opts[this.id];
    $('#selectedproduct').fadeOut(300, function () {
        $(this).text(text).fadeIn(300);
    });

});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TPkZf/3/).

The key to this answer is, really, using an object (similar in principle to an `array`, but with alphanumeric keys), with values stored with keys that are the same as the `id` of the `li` elements you want your users to click. Effectively each time an `li` (that *has* an `id`) is clicked it retrieves the value from the array with the key equal to that `id` with the following line:

```
var text = opts[this.id];
```

This *also* allows you to enter a default message in the event that a new `id` is added without a corresponding value in the object (due to a typo or oversight), for example:

```
var text = opts[this.id] || 'Default message here';
```

This relies on the returned value from the `opts[this.id]` being 'falsey', it would normally be `undefined` if there was no key equal to the `id`, so you could be more strict with a ternary operator:

```
var text = opts[this.id] !== undefined ? opts[this.id] : 'Default message here';
```

This approach also avoids the use of all the `if` assessments and the `is()` method (which makes it considerably cheaper to run).

And, further, by using a JavaScript object to contain the descriptions against the relevent element `id` avoids redeclaring the same variables *every time the click() method is used*.

Further, I've corrected the HTML to enclose the `h3` elements within an `li`.

References:

- jQuery (at the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/)):

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).
  - [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
  - [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: This is much nicer. Do this!

Comment: in my defense, I saw the other one before I even refreshed the page to check this. but I appreciate all of help, y'all are incredible.

Comment: @jaruesink: there's no need for any defense, the answer to accept is the one that best works for you (regardless of the views of everyone else, unless it's *demonstrably* wrong, but even so: it's your choice, and *yours alone*). But thank you for the acceptance, and I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gCFu7/2/).  Be sure to check the HTML for the spans around each section and use this jQuery:

```
$("#calcchooser li").click(function () {
    $("#selectedproduct").text($(this).siblings("h3").text() + " " + $(this).text());
});
```

Comment: I like this, but when I get to my ebook, then it says Ebook Ebook. Also apparently h3 tags shouldn't be inside ul tags (only li).